# SEO influence of location and topic as subdomain and folder

Tags: wordpress, seo, subdomain, sitemap, multilingual

I'm currently developing the layout of my new website. I plan to build a central website and subdomains for different aspects of my online presence.

- name-lastname.de
- portfolio.name-lastname.de
- webdesign.name-lastname.de
- nickname.name-lastname.de

I decided to create the central website as a hub for my other sites because even though the topics and target groups of my sites differ I want them to stay connected. I'll be using Wordpress as my CMS/Blog of choice, WPML for localisation (english / german) and the Wordpress 3.0 Multisite Feature to fuel all networked blogs (subdomains) with the same wordpress installation.

On my central website (name-lastname.de) I'll show excerps of my latest additions to the other sites as well as social media streams and stuff. The content of the other sites are for

1. potential clients/employees,
2. people interested in the web stuff I coded (read: scripts, css and html tricks etc.)
3. people I know and interact with online (more casual content)

What would be the best approach if I want those subdomains for the topics as well as different versions for english and german. I'm not sure I like the /de/ and /en/ approach but en.portfolio.name-lastname.de feels wrong too.

Should I go with language or topic as a subdomain and the other as a folder? Should I register both .de and a neutral tld (.com or .net)?

**< edit >**
After reading Steve H's comment, I'll put the nickname website on a seperate domain, beeing to casual for the other sites. Other then that I'll propably use a language subdirectory either with a topic subdomain or topic subdirectory.
**< /edit >**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is largely down to personal choice, but if I was you I would choose between either totally separate domains for each of your aspects or just have one main domain (name-lastname.de) and just use Wordpress's category's to separate each section.

In terms of tld I would go for .com if you are trying to hit an international market or just use your native tld (.de ?) if not.

I can't really see any advantage with your subdomain approach to either SEO or to the user (unless you want more separation between services, in which case new top level domains would be better), so how about:

name-lastname.de

name-lastname.de/portfolio

name-lastname.de/webdesign

name-lastname.de/nickname (if not too casual)

etc...

So really it's up to you to decide just how separate these concerns are, from your list I think 1 and 2 certainly would match as any clients would be interested in your code / portfolio but perhaps point 3 would be best served on a separate domain if this is indeed too casual / you don't want clients to make too much reference to it.

Lastly in terms of language, could you not leave this up to the user, i.e. choose either English or German as your default language, but just add a link on the page to see the 'other' language. Again I would be reluctant to make 2 versions of the same page in different languages as it would be twice as much work for you to maintain, also in Chrome for example language translation is a trivial thing.

Comment: Update: just had a quick read through WPML doc's, and this plugin basically does what I was explaining in the last paragraph. So in that case you would definitely not want different subdomains for each language as WPML actually creates URL's (not to be confused with actual folders) for each langauge. So you simply just need to create you main blog post in whatever default language you choose, and let WPML do the rest.

Comment: /_1_/I planned to use the WP3.0 Multisite feature to create a domain based network of blogs on my domain for the separate subdomains. I know I can use different themes for different folders in my wordpress install with a theme switcher plugin but I'd somehow prefer the subdomain solution. /_2_/ I know it's possible to use [a cookie for setting the language in WPML](http://wpml.org/forums/topic/setting-the-language-through-a-cookie/) but regarding SEO I think the /de/ and /en/ folders are the better solution for crawlers.

Comment: /_3_/ I think you are right about the additional subdomain for the language. I'll propably go with my native tld and create a folder url structure for english via WPML. /_4_/ I'm undecided if I should stick with subdomains for topics (sharing some authority with my main site) or switch to folders (full SEO authority). SEO wise, folders for topics seem to be a better solution but it will make managing my main navigations, themes and sitemap a bit more complicated. /_5_/ I think you are right about my "casual nickname website". I'll exclude that and put it on a seperate domain.

Comment: Hi kad_lancer, i'm glad you took some of my options on board, as I guess my main point was to try not to give yourself too much work to do. I think many people (myself included) had grand plans of creating subdomain's and tld's for all sort's of website's and topics, but we inevitable find out that having separate domains for each idea means we have to actually maintain each domain enough to keep people's interested. Sharing info on one domain gives you a bit of slack as if one topic area is kinda light you can make up for it in another area, offering more useful info to the visitor in place.

Comment: There is no reason why you can't start off with a shared blog and then if required move to a separate domain for each topic as and when required, i.e. growing your blog's rather than putting yourself under pressure from the get go. Good call on moving the nickname stuff to another domain, I think is the right decision. I think WP category's for topics is the best way, and I disagree I think this way would actually make your nav's and sitemap much easier to manage, as you can simply create the WP nav for each topic, many ways you could do it. Good luck with your endeavours.

Comment: I took (half) a nights sleep over your last answer before commenting and I think that was a good idea. After rethinking my goals and reading your comments I think you are right. Should I later on move my stuff to seperate (sub)domains, I can still redirect old entries with little effort. I accepted your answer and upvoted your comments, they were indeed of great value for me. Over-thinking and over-optimizing a solution is an easy trap to fall into.

Comment: "Over-thinking and over-optimizing a solution is an easy trap to fall into" - I think you hit the nail on the head. Thanks, glad I could offer a different perspective and I wish you luck in your blogging endeavours.